# How to retrieve the resolved url

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a windows authenticated site. When I load the URL in browser, it will redirect automatically by logging into the web site using Windows Authentication. 
I am trying to get a request to a site using JavaScript, also I am able to alert the resolved page data i.e. even through JavaScript windows authentication is done.

My question is after resolving to the authenticated page, my page URL also get changed, so is there any way to retrieve the URL...

For suppose if I give http://mysite.com then after authentication it is resolved to something like this http://mysite.com/{user-id}

Now I want to get the user id using JavaScript. Can some one please help me here...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL with `window.location`.

If your URL really is as simple as `http://mysite.com/1`, for example, you can get the ID with

```
var user_id = parseInt(window.location.pathname.substr(1), 10);
```

Comment: Thanks and it is true... we can get location with Window.location but I don't want to load the entire page. I just wanted to request using the XML Http request and get the resolved URL where in the resolved URL has the user id which i want to use it other side.